# using fetch with-in require js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, fetch

I'm trying to learn require js, and am working on extending the multi page demo found from here: https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage with fetch.

From the demo code in the git repo above, I have modified the www/js/app/model/m1.js code to look like this.  Everything else from the demo is basically the same.

```
define(['./Base','fetch'], function (Base) {

    var m1 = fetch('data/people.json')
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    });

    return new Base(m1);

});
```

(I have fetch polyfil loading as a shim, that is why it is included in the define arguments - but dev on latest chrome which has support for fetch)

Ideally this returns a new Base object that uses the resolved json from the fetch to populate its data source. this.data = data, when the new Base object is created.

Currently though, it seems I only get the promise back and can't get the json out.  Though if I console.log the promise I can see the successful response in there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is how you assign to `m1`. You can't use the return value of `fetch`. The execution order of your code is as follows: start fetching, create and return `Base`, receive data from fetch. So you don't have the data yet when you're building `Base`. That's a common pattern (and pittfall) in JS. Can you work with a callback or Promise?

```
define(['./Base','fetch'], function (Base, callback) {
    fetch('data/people.json')
    .then(function(response) {
        callback(response.json());
        // or maybe you want 
        //Base(response.json());
    });
});
```